# Vaadin example from 'Book of Vaadin' is not compiled

Tags: java, vaadin

I am trying to re-create some of Vaadin examples from their book of Vaadin (LayoutExample.java). I am using their latest version v7. However, when trying to compile the following code, the compiler complains that `addComponent` in the last line is not defined for the type `Panel`. My question is, should the examples in the book of Vaadin be compiled with a different version of Vaadin?

I am evaluating Vaadin for a project but so far I have found many examples on their website that do not compile with the latest Vaadin library. Have i missed something?

```
    HorizontalLayout horlayout = new HorizontalLayout();

    Panel menuContainer = new Panel("The Possible Places");
    horlayout.addComponent(menuContainer);

    // A menu tree, fill it later.
    Tree menu = new Tree();
    menuContainer.addComponent(menu);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after reading their api documentation, i realized that a `Panel` holds one and only one component, which should be supplied in the constructor. The following code solved my problem but I am just wondering when they are going to update their example, and subsequently their book of vaadin!

```
    // A menu tree, fill it later.
    Tree menu = new Tree();
    menu.setSizeUndefined();

    // Layout for the menu area. Wrap the menu in a Panel to allow
    // scrollbar.
    Panel menuContainer = new Panel("The Possible Places", menu);
```

Answer (score 1):

As it states in [the preface of the Book Of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/preface.html)

> Writing this manual is an ongoing work and it is rarely completely up-to-date with the quick-evolving product. This version is a snapshot taken soon after the release of Vaadin 7.
>
> While this edition is mostly updated for Vaadin 7, it may still contain some outdated content related to Vaadin 6.

Of course, this is not ideal; if you could report the URL that contains the outdated example to the [Vaadin forum](https://vaadin.com/forum), it could be corrected and this will help other users.

Comment: Although I am a bit disappointed with the lack of compatibility, I found Vaadin the best platform for my project. I will most certainly report everything to that forum. Thanks.